# PHP: Trouble using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I used this php code in order to make a select on my database:

```
 $check = 'true';
    $request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username'])); 
    $query_username=sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$request'");

    $database= mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_select_db($mydatabase, $database);

    $resultUsers = mysql_query($query_username, $mydb) or die(mysql_error());
    $usernameFound= mysql_num_rows($resultUsers);

    if ($usernameFound> 0) { 
        $check = 'false'; 
    }
```

The above code works good. 
But now I'm trying to convert it using `mysqli`. So I rewrited the code in this way:

```
$connectiondb = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username'])); 
    $query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM utente WHERE username = '$request'"); 

    if(!$result = $connectiondb->query($query)){
        die('Error in query execution [' . $connectiondb->error . ']');
      }
    $rows = $result->num_rows();

    $result->free();
    $connectiondb->close();
    if($rows>0){
     $check = 'false'; 
    }
```

But this does not work! No error is generated, but I can't obtain the right result.

What can be the problem?

Comment: why do you need number of rows?

Comment: Why do you keep the same injection you had with old mysql?

Comment: Someone can tell me the reason of downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$rows = $result->num_rows;`
I also recommend you switch to using prepared statements when using mysqli, your current code is vulnerable to injections.

Comment: +1 good identifying the actual issue and telling about the vulnerability.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld then why don't you upvote this answer? it's SO in the end and if you find it useful…